# Including glib.h in a CMake project

Tags: cmake, glib

Trying to compile a library in Ubuntu with CMake and one of the file includes glib.h. The package is installed and `glib.h` is in `/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h`.

I added the following but compiler still cannot find glib.h.

```
FIND_PACKAGE(glib-2.0)
IF (glib-2.0_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${glib-2.0_INCLUDE_DIR})
ENDIF()
```

Anyone know what package I are suppose to look for?

Actual code that I ended up using is

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GLIB_PKG glib-2.0)

if (GLIB_PKG_FOUND)
    message(Found glib-2.0)
include_directories(${GLIB_PKG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you go through the link: [How package finding works](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries).

As a reference, you can have a look at this [CMake Module](http://gitorious.org/gammu/mainline/blobs/9d71b23a73186aad73453973e05a94fb36e16f4f/cmake/FindGlib.cmake) for finding glib2.

The line of your interest here is:

```
find_path(GLIB_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES glib.h PATH_SUFFIXES glib-2.0)
```

I suggest you copy this module in your `<project root>/cmake/` directory. And, then use a `find_package` in your root CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Second if broken link.

Comment: Yes, the link is broken. I really would like to see the example CMake module

Comment: I believe this might be it https://github.com/gammu/gammu/blob/master/cmake/FindGlib.cmake