# Change Glib with CMake

Tags: cmake, glib

## The Problem:

So, I'm writing an application in C that uses the glib's hash table function. Unfortunately, because Homebrew installs glib into a subdirectory, pre-written includes are broken, and it completely fails to compile. Part of the problem is related to the tendency glib has to hide itself, but I'm aware of how to solve this, and have written a makefile that works. However, I would still prefer to be able to use my IDE as usual, and this seems like it may cause other problems in the future, so I am wondering whether anybody has any advice.
Below is the makefile, cmakelists.txt and errors.

Please note that my problem is not including CMake, it is due to the fact that Homebrew has installed it to `/usr/lib/local/glib-2.0/glib.h`, and the header files it includes are under `/usr/lib/local/glib-2.0/glib/`. Unfortunately, all of glibs header include the others as such

```
#include <glib/galloca.h>
#include <glib/garray.h>
#include <glib/gasyncqueue.h>
#include <glib/gatomic.h>
#include <glib/[...]>
```

where these should be

```
#include <glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib/garray.h>
```

e.t.c, You get the idea

#### Makefile

```
# Compiler
CC = gcc
#CFlags
CFlags = -g -Wall -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lglib-2.0 -lintl -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.18.9/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6_1/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/libepoxy/1.3.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.38.1/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/1.2.4/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.38.1/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/atk/2.18.0_1/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6_1/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.34.0/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6.3/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.21/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.32.3/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.21/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include

TARGET = main
all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c
    $(CC) $(CFlags) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c
clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

#### Compile Errors

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/ennis/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/85d4a0ab/85d4a0ab/Debug --target all -- -j 4
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/TaskAppBuilder_C.dir/main.c.o
In file included from /Users/ennis/TaskAppBuilder-C/main.c:4:
In file included from /Users/ennis/TaskAppBuilder-C/main.h:15:
In file included from /Users/ennis/TaskAppBuilder-C/glib.h:30:
/usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib.h/galloc.h:32:10: fatal error: 'galloc.h' file not found
#include <galloc.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TaskAppBuilder_C.dir/main.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TaskAppBuilder_C.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(TaskAppBuilder_C)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c11")


set(SOURCE_FILES main.c main.h)
add_executable(TaskAppBuilder_C ${SOURCE_FILES} main.c main.h)
```

Comment: 1- Seems that galloc is not found, do you have it? 2.- Can you post your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @Joel: Yes, the entire glib library is installed, this is exemplified by the fact that it can be compiled using the makefile above. Note, this makefile will only work on a mac with glib installed using Homebrew.

Comment: Did you try telling cmake where to find glib? Other thing..never manually edit cmake's makefiles...they always are overwritten per modification of the cache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including glib.h in a CMake project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383830/including-glib-h-in-a-cmake-project)

Comment: I have not modified the CMake generated makefile, as I'm well aware it rewrites it, I instead wrote my own one, CMake is a seperate section of this. Just put the makefile there because, rather than it being the problem of including it, it is including it from an unusual directory, as Homebrew has installed it to different location. It is installed to /usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/glib.h, and the other headers are in a subdirectory of that, meaning that glib.h tries to include files in the wrong directory, as do all the other headers. This is my problem

Comment: You should not write your own Makefile, you get one generated from CMake. The duplicate question answers you how to set the different include directory.

Comment: Ok, have looked at the above question again and do believe it answers my question. However. I see nothing wrong with writing your own make file. In large projects it is necessary to use something to do it for u, but in 1, 2 or 4 file projects there is no need. As I stated above, the make file I made is not related to CMake in anyway, it is not an editors CMake makefile nor is it in a directory related to it. It is completely isolated from all of cmakes files.

Comment: Writing your own Makefiles is fine. But then don't use CMake in your project  and don't tag your question with [cmake]. Mixing autogenerated and handwritten Makefiles will cause problems unless you really know what you're doing.